# How to convert date from string format to numeric?

Tags: r, lubridate

Results I found containing date formatting usually already start as a numeric and don't address the issue I'm looking for. I just want to be able to change the formatted date "January 1 2022" to numeric.  Would the best way be to put the column containing the dates into a variable or is there a simpler way?

```
glimpse(df2)
$ G <numeric> " June 28 2021"
$ X <chr> "John Doe"
$ O <chr> "Attended"

datecolumn <- select(df2,G)  
date <- as.Date.numeric(datecolumn)
```

After that I can just adjust using lubridate's as.Date function right?

Desired output:

```
$ G <chr> " 06/28/21"
$ X <chr> "John Doe"
$ O <chr> "Attended"
```

Comment: use `lubridate::mdy(df2$G)`

Comment: @onyambu didn't think it would be that simple, thank you! But how would I be able to make sure the rest of my data lines up with the dates?

Comment: You can change the format of your date column within the data frame using `df2 %>% mutate(G = lubridate::mdy(G))`

Comment: Base R: `df2$G |> strptime("%B %d %Y") |> format("%m/%d/%y")`, details are shown in `?strptime`.

Comment: @Seth worked perfectly! Thank you everybody for the help, I have a lot to learn.